# SSAS OLAP Cube Output Date Format mm/dd/yy to yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: sql-server, excel, date, ssas, olap-cube

I have deployed an SQL Server 2012 on a Windows Server en-us.

Now my dates on Analysis services are in this format MM/dd/yyyy. the company is not American, therefore I would like to change it to yyyy-MM-dd.

Everything seems to be properly configured, however, SSAS is refusing to output the dates in the desired format.

[Query on SQL Database engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsz60.jpg)

[Windows Server Regional Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhoP6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

an easy and fast way is to create a computed column on DimDate in SSMS, and specify this a name value for your datekey. Let me if that works.

```
ALTER TABLE [Dim].[Date] ADD AlternateDateFormat AS convert(date,[FullDate], 111);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my column is allready on the correct format convert(date,[FullDate], 111).
My problem is that SSAS modify the display format, example : 
2016-04-28 ---> 4/28/2016.
I have changed the region date format but it doesn't work.

Comment: Same cube has been published on two machines and date format is different.
Does anyone know what setting has impact on date format which is displayed?